# TinyBox Form Bug

Tags: php, javascript, html

i try to use the tinybox Javascript.

Now i will try to use it on submit, but i don't know how!?

```
<div id="add">
<form name="addVoc" action="javascript:TINY.box.show('system/import.php',1,300,150,1);" method="post" onsubmit='return checkForm();'>
    <img src="images/gb.png" width="13px" height="8px"> English: <input type="text" name="English" class="addBox" />
    <img src="images/de.png" width="13px" height="8px"> German: <input type="text" name="German" class="addBoxD" /><br><br>
    <img src="images/icon_hinweis.gif" width="10px" height="10px"> Add Voc <input type="submit" class="sbutton" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

Now it shows me the tinybox but nothing happens, the box is empty.

This is my JS checkForm()

```
    function checkForm(){

        if (document.forms["addVoc"].English.value==""){
            alert('Upps!'); 
            return false;
        }
        if (document.forms["addVoc"].German.value==""){
            alert('Upps!');
            return false;
        }
return true;
    }
```

In my Html Head i linked the Tinybox CSS and JS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tinybox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinybox.js"></script>
```

here is the import.php:

```
<?php
include 'include/connect.php';

$db_link = mysql_connect (MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_BENUTZER, MYSQL_KENNWORT);
if (!$db_link)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("vokabel", $db_link);

$sql="INSERT INTO word (Englisch, Deutsch)
VALUES
('$_POST[Englisch]','$_POST[Deutsch]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$db_link))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "Vokabel wurde hinzugefügt!";

mysql_close($db_link)
?>
```

I'm new on JS, i hope some one can help me... without tinybox it works perfectly

Thank you very mutch

Comment: Do not use TinyBox.
It's undocumented and the source code is obfuscated.
You'll have trouble all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have

```
<input type="text" name="Deutsch" class="addBoxD" />
```

I suspect

```
if (document.forms["addVoc"].German.value==""){
```

should read

```
if (document.forms["addVoc"].Deutsch.value==""){
```

Also, you should add

```
return true;
```

to the last line of the `checkForm()` function.

I doubt either of these will fix your tinybox problem - this most likely because the `system/import.php` does not output anything.

Load `system/import.php` in your browser and make sure you get the output you expect. If you do, make sure that `system/import.php` is the correct **relative** path from the current page to get to `import.php`. If all of this is correct, please edit the question to include the source code of `import.php`.

Having said all that, it does seem a little odd to have the tiny box called as the `action` attribute of the form - are you *sure* this is what you want to do? What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

**EDIT**

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="add">
<form name="addVoc" action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="return checkForm();">
    <img src="images/gb.png" width="13px" height="8px"> Englisch: <input type="text" name="Englisch" class="addBox" />
    <img src="images/de.png" width="13px" height="8px"> Deutsch: <input type="text" name="Deutsch" class="addBoxD" /><br><br>
    <img src="images/icon_hinweis.gif" width="10px" height="10px"> Add Voc <input type="submit" class="sbutton" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function checkForm(){

    if (document.forms["addVoc"].Englisch.value=="") {
        alert('Upps!'); 
        return false;
    }
    if (document.forms["addVoc"].Deutsch.value==""){
        alert('Upps!');
        return false;
    }

    TINY.box.show('system/import.php?Englisch='+document.forms["addVoc"].Englisch.value+'&Deutsch='+document.forms["addVoc"].Deutsch.value,1,300,150,1);

    return false;

}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

  include 'include/connect.php';

  if (!$db_link = mysql_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_BENUTZER, MYSQL_KENNWORT)) {
    die('Konnte keine Verbindung: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("vokabel", $db_link);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO `word` 
            (`Englisch`, `Deutsch`)
          VALUES
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Englisch'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Deutsch'])."')";

  if (!mysql_query($sql,$db_link)) {
    die('Fehler: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  echo "Vokabel wurde hinzugefügt!";

  mysql_close($db_link)

?>
```

**ANOTHER EDIT**

If you are using Tinybox 2, change this line:

```
TINY.box.show('system/import.php?Englisch='+document.forms["addVoc"].Englisch.value+'&Deutsch='+document.forms["addVoc"].Deutsch.value,1,300,150,1);
```

To this:

```
TINY.box.show({url:'system/import.php',post:'Englisch='+document.forms["addVoc"].Englisch.value+'&Deutsch='+document.forms["addVoc"].Deutsch.value,width:300,height:150});
```

And change the two occurences of `$_GET` in `import.php` to `$_POST`.

Comment: ah sry i translate it to english because i'm german and i forgot the rest :-) but i added return true; but nothing happens, without tinybox it works perfectly -.- i updated the code in my question, i try to open the tinybox by submission and not a new window

Comment: :-( thx but it doesn't work...i search in google and someone says, i need a new function with ajax ...but i doesn't know anything about ajax

Comment: Do you still get the same result (shows a box but with no text)?

Comment: look http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/338/ajaxg.png/ and http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/607/screennq.png/

Comment: I still think the above should work - if you load `import.php` in a browser, what happens? You should see some text, probably `Vokabel wurde hinzugefügt!` (and a blank row will be inserted into the database) - if you just get a blank page/no row inserted, you probably have a syntax error in `include/connect.php`

Comment: yes it came the text: Vokabel wurde hinzugefügt! and in the database there is my inserts (hello - hallo), works fine, only with tinybox it will not work :-(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4659/discussion-between-matthias-and-daverandom)

Comment: Which version of tinybox are you using? If you are using [Tinybox2](http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/), it needs to be called in a slightly different way, which may be the problem - if you are not using Tinybox2, try switching to that.